# Unable to create child instance for one-to-many on Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am creating parent and child instance using sequlize, but it throws following error.

```
Site.hasMany(Group,{as:'groups'});
Group.belongsTo(Site);

//not working
Site.create(siteData).then((site)=>{
  site.addGroups(groupData).then(()=>{  //also tried addGroup
    next();
  });
});

//this works
Site.create(siteData).then((site)=>{
 groupData.SiteId=site.id;
 Group.create(groupData).then(()=>{
    next();
 });
});
```

Error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: val.replace is not a function
>       at Object.SqlString.escape (c:\APi\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:61:15)
>       at Object.QueryGenerator.escape (c:\APi\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:983:22)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is necessary for it to work but have you tried building a Group sequelize instance and then running add groups? var instance =Site.build(groupData) and pass that instance to addGroups. And what does your table schemas look like for Site and Group? How did you write the relationships in sequelize?

Comment: Hi @CameronBillings, Group alone works, Even the second option works as displayed in my code above. I have created relation using first two line as I shown Above. However I removed some code which syncs the schema to keep the code above simple. May I know what that Site.build(groupData) does? as per the schema My Group table has SiteId within it.

Comment: Group.build(groupData) would just return the Sequelize instance of a Group object using the groupData. So it would attach Sequelize methods and such to the instance. The addAssociation() method might expect to contain a Sequelize instance and not just a plain object that "represents" a Sequelize instance.http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/

Comment: Make sense, Looks this your suggestion would fix the issue i am facing. I will give a try and update you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a task and different schedule so you can try something like this **and** you can create the bulk of schedule or single task as well just change `bulkeCreate` to `create`

```
    var ts=req.body.task_time;


    tasks.create(req.body).then(function (taskvalues) {

         //for adding taskId with each object to prepare object for bulk

         for(var i=0;i<ts.length;i++)

         ts[i].taskId = taskvalues.id;

        taskschedule.bulkCreate(ts,{ individualHooks: true }).then(function (allschedule) {

            res.status(200).json({"message":"Post saved successfully"});

        }).catch(function (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err)
        }).catch(function (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);

        })

    })
```

Your json for taskschedule and whatever value set for task in post body

```
 "task_time": [
  {
    "shift": "m",
    "date": "01/23/2017",
    "start_time": "2017-01-22 19:00:00",
    "end_time": "2017-01-23 19:00:00",
      "status":"2",
      "user_id":"12"
  },

  {
    "shift": "m",
    "date": "01/23/2017",
    "start_time": "2017-01-22 19:00:00",
    "end_time": "2017-01-23 19:00:00",
      "status":"2",
      "user_id":"12"
  }

],
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have any code like below adding custom properties to Object, you will face this issue.

```
Object.prototype.xxx = function(o) {
  ...
}
```

When Sequelize compose sql, it loops over all the properties of parameter, which will include this custom property.