# Sequelize.js Node.js: How to Pass Already Created Object to Create Many-to-Many relationship?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

From this post: [Node.js / Sequelize.js / Express.js - How to insert into many-to-many association? (sync/async?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921074/node-js-sequelize-js-express-js-how-to-insert-into-many-to-many-associatio)

The answer show only when you create Individual and Email, however, I want to create an Individual with an already created email.

Original answer to correctly create Individual and Email after one another:

```
models.Individual.create({
  name: "Test"
}).then(function(createdIndividual) { // note the argument
  models.Email.create({
    address: "test@gmail.com"
  }).then(function(createdEmail) { // note the argument
    createdIndividual.addEmail(createdEmail)
      .then(function(addedEmail) { // note th-- well you get the idea :)
        console.log("Success");
      });
  })
});
```

To create an individual with an already created email, I modified into this:

```
models.Individual.create({
  name: "Test"
}).then(function(createdIndividual) { // note the argument
    //This email id exists in the Email table.
    var email = {
        id: 1
    }
    createdIndividual.addEmail(email)
    .then(function(addedEmail) {
        console.log("Success");
    });
});
```

Then I got this error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: val.replace is not a function
        at Object.SqlString.escape (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:63:15)
        at Object.QueryGenerator.escape (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:977:22)
        at /Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2203:23
        at Array.map (native)
        at Object.QueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2202:49)
        at /Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1903:25
        at /Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4389:15
        at baseForOwn (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2652:24)
        at Function.forOwn (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:12254:24)
        at Object.QueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1902:9)
        at Object.QueryGenerator.getWhereConditions (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2337:19)
        at Object.QueryGenerator.selectQuery (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1451:28)
        at QueryInterface.select (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:669:25)
        at .<anonymous> (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1390:32)
        at tryCatcher (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/ponds_web/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
```

I think this error because my email object is not a Sequelize object.

Questions in mind:

Should we convert the email object into a Sequalize object by query from Email models? Will it work?

What's the better way to convert that object into Sequalize, as clean code and performance are concerned?

What if I have multiple emails to be added into Individual_Email when creating a new Product? Like more than 1 email ids.

Please help to advice. Thanks.

Comment: please see this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305458/1159775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the problem is that email is not a sequelize object. It would work if you retrieve it from database before adding it. On the other hand sequelize allows you to set childs by id. So you can do something like this:

```
models.Individual.create({
  name: "Test"
}).then(function(createdIndividual) {
    createdIndividual.setEmails([emailIds]) //emails id array
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Success");
    });
});
```